# Не работает интернет в linux Mint после установки новой материнской платы

Tags: linux, администрирование, linux-mint, драйвер

После установки новой мат платы в ОС linux Mint 20 перестал работать интернет, просто перечеркнутый значок сети, звук есть, так же на этом же пк в Win10 дрова подтянулись автоматом при первом включении. Подозреваю дрова на линуксе не установились. Подскажите можно как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: lsusb/lspci показывает что то о Вашей карте?  dmesg, `ifconfig` / `ip address` ?

Answer (score 0):

Для материнских плат на чипсете Z490 нужно установить драйвер от риалтек 2,5G ethernet и все заработает